# Spring boot JPA without Spring data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm gradually introducing Spring Boot to a Spring JPA project. My intent was to first introduce Spring Boot, than at some later stage Spring Data, but I was not able to find any examples (nor a suitable starter) that uses Spring Boot + JPA **without** Spring Data.

How come? Is there any benefit of introducing Spring Boot to Spring JPA project, without Spring Data, or does it make sense only with Spring Data in place.

Any article link or example code would be helpfull and appreciated, thanks

**More context**

I'm working with a live project so every change introduces risk. We're discussing of moving from XML to JAVA based configuration, and I'm advocating adopting Spring Boot at a same time, but I lack persuasive selling points.

Personally, I want to include Spring Boot on all layers to boost future productivity, but I need to argue better the direct immediate benefits of using it in our Service/DAO module which is at the moment based on Spring/JPA/Hibernate with the good old manual CRUD implementations.

So I need selling points for using Spring Boot on a persistence layer, but ones that span beyond Spring Data (e.g. configuration gains, maintenance, testing...anything)

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no [Spring JPA](https://spring.io/projects). There is however, [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) which is Spring Data with a JPA backend. Does that answer your question?

Comment: there's no spring boot spring jpa starter, this is clear. But I'm having a Spring project that is using JPA/Hibernate that I would,like to gear more towards Spring Boot, for all the good stuff going on there. I would like to do it step at the time, so without introducing Spring Data. But wondering if that makes sense, what would be an immediate gain (code, configuration etc. ) how to justify it to my project manager.

Comment: There is no Spring JPA support without Spring Data. Spring JPA _depends on_ Spring Data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As folks have said above, there is no Spring Boot JPA. It's either Spring Boot Data JPA, or JPA on its own.

The immediate benefits that I could think of:

- With Spring Data JPA you don't write the Dao layer. For all CRUD operations, the CrudRepository interface gives you all you need. When that is not enough, all you have to use is the @Query annotation to fine-tune your SQLs
- Configuration by convention. For example, with Spring Boot, just having the H2 dependency in the classpath gets Spring to use the H2 in-memory database, gives you Datasource configuration and transaction management (only at the JPA repository level) by default
- Ability to create micro-services. With Spring Boot, you can create micro services that can be deployed and run on a number of boxes with java -jar ...
- You can enable annotation-based transaction with one simple annotation: @EnableTransactionManagement
- Java configuration over XML. This advantage is not to be underestimated
- A lot less code (the DAO layer) means also a lot less maintenance
- The native ability to provide a RESTful API around data: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

It all depends where your company is heading for. If they want to deliver business value faster and move towards more a DevOps operating model, then the above advantages should be enough selling points for any organisation

Answer (score 4):

Spring wiht JPA (for example Hibernate) but without Spring-Data-Jpa means that you direct interact with the JPA Entity manager and. Typical you use it to implement your own DAO from it and use the `@Respository` annotation.

```
@Respository
public class UserDao {
    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

    public User findUserByLogin(Sting login) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Even if there is no starter project, you could use a Spring-Data-JPA project, and implement the Repository in this old fashion style. *(And then you could show how simple it become when you just write Spring-Data-JPA interfaces)*

Comment: thanks Ralph for the answer. I've added more context to the question. I need more benefits of using Spring Boot to support JPA. Using spring data is not so much an advantage, as we're having manual generic implementations where we already use most likely the same patterns underlying spring data. So search, pagination, generic projections etc. we already have a solid coverage for. Can you remember anything else that would be a good selling point for introducing spring boot and its JPA support that goes beyond using Spring Data?

Comment: @learnAndImprove: I  (personal opinion) dont like Spring Boot, because it requires to learn a new configuration style and if you learned it, you will notice this is not powerfull enought so that that you need to learn plain spring configuration too. -- so no I have no selling point for Boot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, `spring-boot` means more convenient not any independent business feature.

In other words, `spring-boot` helps you to start, configure your application in some automatically way. But you can do that without `spring-boot` with your own specific configuration.

So, you are going to use `spring-boot` in your application means you are going to use `spring-boot`'s auto configuration feature with your original application.

Actually, `Spring JPA` implemented in `spring-data-jpa` is what you are looking for not `spring-boot`. Of course, `spring-boot` can simplify your work dramatically.