# Spring Boot JPA returns correct count but no data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Evening,

I have a Spring application that is connected to a PostgresSQL db. I can connect to the database and see that the query is returning the correct number of elements for the array but nothing in them:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/books
[{},{},{}]%
```

My `Book` model looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Entity
public class Book {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  
  private String name;
  private String author;
  private BigDecimal price;

  public Book() {}

  public Book(String name, String author, BigDecimal price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

and the controller:

```
@RestController
public class BookController {

  @Autowired
  private BookRepository repository;

  // Find
  @GetMapping("/books")
  List<Book> findAll() {
    List<Book> books = repository.findAll();
    System.out.println(books);

    return repository.findAll();
  }

}
```

I've looked at these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285695/spring-boot-jpa-query-returns-no-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673310/spring-boot-jpa-without-spring-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014669/spring-boot-jpa-and-mysql-returns-empty-results#36015886) but those answers didn't fit with this.

What am I not doing to see data come back?

Comment: Your entity needs to have getters/setters for serialization/deserialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your entity to be serialized by Spring the entity needs to have getters for its properties. You could use [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) to auto-generate getter/setters for you entity properties or just write them your own.

Comment: Yeah that appears to be the case; I didn;t go with lombok as I just wrote them myself.